# Can one make a siyum on “shas bavli” if he did not also finish the masechtos mishnayos that do not have gemara bavli on them?

Tags: talmud-gemara, siyum, daf-yomi

I have heard that to make a siyum on shas bavli one must finish shisha sidrei mishna (and all bavli that there is). Is one required to learn the entire shisha sidrei mishna as well as all of the existing talmud bavli or can one say the hadran on shas bavli with the full daf yomi masechtos?

Comment: What does "shas bavli" mean?

Comment: You are right - thank you- i guess that was part of the question effectively answered/explained by the post below.

Comment: How about machetos ketanos?

Comment: I saw this question asked to Rav Chaim Kanievski. There are about a thousand sefarim that could be in, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=2367) site:

"This celebration is commonly referred to as the "Siyum HaShas," but technically speaking, this term is inaccurate. The word "Shas" is an acronym for the words, "Shisha Sedarim," referring to the six sections of the Mishna. The Daf Yomi program completes the entire Talmud Bavli, but the Talmud Bavli does not cover all six sections of the Mishna. For example, there is no tractate of Talmud Bavli on the section of Zera’im (with the exception of Masechet Berachot), or on most of the section of Taharot. Therefore, when reciting the "Hadran" text at the Siyum celebration, one should ensure to recite "Talmud Bavli," and not "Shas" or "Shisha Sedarim." "

Comment: It does cover all six _s'darim_. Not every _maseches_, though.